# Calling appropriate method depending on ARGV using a switch case

Tags: ruby

Apparently (according to rubocop), my method is too long and has high cyclomatic complexity. How do I fix this?

```
  def initialize(args)
    case args.join(' ')
    when /\Asignup/
      signup
    when 'logout'
      logout
    when 'login'
      login
    when 'create'
      create
    when 'keys:add'
      keys_add
    when 'infrastructure spawn'
      spawn
    when 'infrastructure despawn'
      despawn
    else
      puts "Unknown command #{args.join(' ')}\n\n#{help}"
      exit 1
    end
  end
```

Comment: This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1231/42632).

Answer (score 1):

There are many gems, like GLI or Thor, that can make developing command line apps easier.

Other than that one suggestions for cleaning up your code might be something similar to:

```
COMMANDS = {
  /\Asignup/             => :signup,
  'logout'               => :logout,
  ...
  'infrastructure spawn' => :spawn
}

def initialize(args)
  command = args.join(' ')
  COMMANDS.each do |cmd, method| 
    if cmd === command
     return send(method)  
  end
  puts "Unknown command #{cmd}\n\n#{help}"
  exit 1
end
```

Answer (score -2):

After about half an hour of thinking I came up with this and rubocop doesn't complain now. Pasting here for future reference.

I realized the need to split the case block. It turns out there were three categories of statements in the case block. Also I made modifications to the "downstream" methods so that they return non nil.

```
 def initialize(args)
    processed = process_user_login_command(args.join(' ')) ||
                process_user_other_command(args.join(' ')) ||
                process_admin_command(args.join(' '))
    puts "Unknown command #{args.join(' ')}\n\n#{help}" unless processed
    exit 1 unless processed
  end

  def process_user_login_command(arguments)
    case arguments
    when /\Asignup/
      signup
    when 'logout'
      logout
    when 'login'
      login
    end
  end

  def process_user_other_command(arguments)
    case arguments
    when 'create'
      create
    when 'keys_add'
      keys_add
    end
  end

  def process_admin_command(arguments)
    case arguments
    when 'infrastructure spawn'
      spawn
    when 'infrastructure despawn'
      despawn
    end
  end
```

I believe these two lines can be written using the ruby `abort expr` syntax. But I haven't done it here.

```
puts "Unknown command #{args.join(' ')}\n\n#{help}" unless processed
exit 1 unless processed
```

Comment: Seems like this was done mainly be extracting to multiple methods? I don't quite understand the reason for using `&& true` though

Comment: In my opinion, the fact that this solution avoids a Rubocop complaint is sufficient justification for this answer not to be deleted. However, it is not enough of justification to save it from my downvote. This solution is worse in so many other respects. It's longer. It's harder to read. It does weird things with the return values. The worst is that its overall cyclomatic complexity has _increased_ — it's just that Rubocop is too stupid to tell you about it.